# PHP: insert into associative array by index?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
$example = array("car"=>"red", "banana"=>"yellow", etc...)
```

Is it possible to alter a value of the array by index instead of key value like

```
$example[0] = "blue";
```

So that the array now looks like

```
$example = array("car"=>"blue", "banana"=>"yellow", etc...)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking I know you can't, but I didn't know if there was a function that I'm not seeing that would allow it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
$e = array("car"=>"red", "banana"=>"yellow");
$keys = array_keys($e);
$e[$keys[0]] = 'blue';

var_dump($e);
```

the output is

```
array(2) { ["car"]=> string(4) "blue" ["banana"]=> string(6) "yellow" }
```